# Discrete Mathematics help: $2017^{2017}$ mod $13$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm not too sure how I would go about solving $2017^{2017}$ mod $13$.

Comment: General question here [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606780/modular-arithmetic-problem-mod-13

Comment: You can reduce the problem in two ways to a smaller one. First observe that $2017 \pmod {13}  = 2$, so that $2017^{a} \pmod {13} = (13 * x +2 )^{2017} \pmod {13}$, which is just $2^{2017} \pmod {13}$ because the remaining terms in the expansion are multiples of $13$.  Second, observe that $2^b \pmod {13}$ produces all the numbers $1,2,\ldots,12$ as $b$ takes values $1,2,\ldots,$ and is periodic with period $12$.  Since $2017 \pmod {12} = 1$, we have that $2^{2017} \pmod {13} = 2^1 \pmod {13} = 2$.

Comment: If you generalize the second method in my previous comment, you get Fermat's little theorem. If $p$ is a prime, then the set of integers $\{1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$ forms a group under multiplication $\pmod p$.  Hence, every element in this group has order $p-1$.  This implies that $k^{p-1}$ is the identity group element for each $k=1,2,\ldots,p-1$,  This gives Fermat's little theorem that $k^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ for each positive integer $k$. This means $k^b \pmod p$ generates the numbers $1,\ldots,p-1$ in some order as $b$ takes values $1,2,\ldots$ and this sequence is periodic,  period $p-1$.

Comment: If you find any answer useful, please accept the best answer [See :
How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For these type of questions, always use [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) :

> $$a^{p-1} \equiv 1\pmod p $$
>
> Where $p$ is a prime number and $\gcd(a,p)=1$

Here $p=13$ and $a=2017$

Therefore :

$$2017^{12}\equiv 1\pmod {13}  \implies \left(2017^{12}\right)^{168}\equiv 1^{168}\pmod {13} $$

Hence :

$$2017^{2016} \equiv 1\pmod {13}$$

Multiplying $2017$ both the sides :

$$2017^{2017} \equiv 2017 \pmod {13} \equiv 2 \pmod{13}$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that $2017 \equiv 2\pmod {13} $. And using Fermat's Little Theorem we have:

$$2^{12} \equiv 1\pmod {13} $$

Hence,

$$2017^{2017} \equiv 2^{2017} \equiv 2 \cdot (2^{12})^{168} \equiv 2 \cdot 1 = 2 \pmod {13} $$

Comment: Nice that you gave two approaches. +1