# Calculating modular exponentiation

Tags: number-theory

One of the question at HW in Number Theory was calculating $$147^{147}\mod 13$$
We didn't see much about the modular properties yet, so I am kind of stuck.
Could someone give a hint or a direction how to approach it?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to ask about $147^{147}\bmod{13}$?

Comment: Also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2256865/discrete-mathematics-help-20172017-mod-13?noredirect=1&lq=1) might be helpful.

Comment: First step: since $147\equiv 4 \bmod 13$, $147^{147}\equiv 4^{147} \bmod 13$. Then $4=2^2$ might be useful. Also look at [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).